Prevent user from directing to the login when user is already logged in vuejs3
Network Manager
import axios from "axios";
import router from "@/router";
import { mixin } from "@/mixins/authMixin";

/**
 * Sends an API request using the specified method, endpoint, data, callback, and optional content type.
 *
 * @param {string} method - The HTTP method for the request (e.g., "get", "post").
 * @param {string} endpoint - The API endpoint to send the request to.
 * @param {object} data - The data to be sent with the request.
 * @param {function} callBack - The callback function to handle the response from the API.
 * @param {string} [contentType="application/json"] - The content type of the request (default is "application/json").
 */
const NetworkManager = {
  apiRequest: function (
    method,
    endpoint,
    data,
    callBack,
    contentType = "application/json",
  ) {
    const apiUrl = import.meta.env.VITE_APP_BACKEND_URL;
    console.log(mixin.data.userData);
    const URL = apiUrl + "/" + endpoint;

    let config = {
      headers: {},
      timeout: apiUrl.timeoutDuration,
    };

    config.headers["Content-Type"] = contentType;
    config.headers["Accept"] = "application/json";

    if (contentType === "multipart/form-data") {
      config.headers["onUploadProgress"] = (progressEvent) =>
        console.log(progressEvent.loaded);
    }

    axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
    axios.defaults.withXSRFToken = true;
    //axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

    if (method === "post") {
      //   console.log(document.cookie)
      axios
        .post(URL, data, config)
        .then(function (e) {
          callBack(e.data);
        })

        .catch(function (error) {
          
          if (error.response) {
            // The request was made and the server responded with a status code
            // that falls out of the range of 2xx
            //Login logic here
            console.log(error.response.data);
            console.log(error.response.status);
            console.log(error.response.headers);
            if (
              error.response.status === 401 ||
              error.response.status === 419
            ) {
              console.log(
                "Unauthorized",
                mixin.data.userData.userDetails.email,
              );

              if (
                mixin.data.userData.userDetails.email == null ||
                mixin.data.userData.userDetails.email == ""
              ) {
                router.push("/login");
              } else {
                mixin.data.userData.reLoginWindow = true;
              }
            } else if (error.request) {
              // The request was made but no response was received
              let obj = {
                code: error.response.status,
                message: error.response.data,
              };
              callBack(obj);
              console.log("Error Request", error.request);
            }

            // Something happened in setting up the request that triggered an Error
          } else {
            let obj = {
              code: error.code,
              message: error.message,
            };
            callBack(obj);
            console.log("Error", error.message);
          }
        });
    }

    if (method === "get") {
      //   console.log(document.cookie)
      axios
        .get(URL, { withCredentials: true })
        .then(function (e) {
          callBack(e.data);
        })

        .catch(function (error) {
          if (error.response) {
            // The request was made and the server responded with a status code
            // that falls out of the range of 2xx
            console.log(error.response.data);
            console.log(error.response.status);
            console.log(error.response.headers);
            if (
              error.response.status === 401 ||
              error.response.status === 419
            ) {
              console.log("Unauthorized");
              let obj = {
                code: error.response.status,
                message: "Unauthorized",
              };
              callBack(obj);
              router.push("/login");
            }
          } else if (error.request) {
            // The request was made but no response was received
            // `error.request` is an instance of XMLHttpRequest in the browser
            // and an instance of http.ClientRequest in node.js
            console.log(error.request);
          } else {
            // Something happened in setting up the request that triggered an Error
            console.log("Error", error.message);
          }
        });
    }
  },
};

export default NetworkManager;

I have implemented when the token is expires on the next api call it routes to the login page. I need to implement this as to riderect to the dashboard when the cookie has an active session. Thank you all for your time, and I genuinely appreciate any help or suggestions you can offer.
